# ng-circle-progress not showing at all

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to show my circle progress, but it refuses to show and I swear that I have everything right. When I go to the page that has `<circle-progress>`, my page shows up blank, even though there is content on it. Tried looking up solutions, but nothing worked, from changing lazy to true to downgrading to version 1.6. Can anyone please help me with this?

I imported it in my app.module
`import { NgCircleProgressModule } from 'ng-circle-progress';`

And also added it under NgModule

```
NgCircleProgressModule.forRoot({
      "radius": 60,
      "space": -10,
      "outerStrokeGradient": true,
      "outerStrokeWidth": 10,
      "outerStrokeColor": "#4882c2",
      "outerStrokeGradientStopColor": "#53a9ff",
      "innerStrokeColor": "#e7e8ea",
      "innerStrokeWidth": 10,
      "title": "UI",
      "animateTitle": false,
      "animationDuration": 1000,
      "showUnits": false,
      "showBackground": false,
      "clockwise": false,
      "startFromZero": false,
      "lazy": true})
```

Lastly, I added it to my "progress.html"

```
<div class="container">
    <circle-progress [percent]="70"  [space]="-10" [radius]="100" [outerStrokeWidth]="10"
      [innerStrokeWidth]="10" [outerStrokeColor]="'#4882c2'" [innerStrokeColor]="'#e7e8ea'" [animation]="true"
      [animationDuration]="1000"></circle-progress>
</div>
```

Comment: which version of Angular are you using please?

Comment: I am using Angular 15

Answer (score 1):

For anyone struggling with the library outside of the root component, here are things you need to check:

- Use the exact same example as the doc's in the `app.module.ts` and `app.component.html`. It will ensure that everything has been installed correctly; you should be able to make the base example work.
- If you are using routing, be sure that your submodule (the one using the circle-progress component) is included in the root module.
- Be sure that the component you're adding the circle-progress to doesn't use the `OnPush` strategy. Your code will compile but the circle-progress component won't load its graphics.

The last point is what made me lose a good half hour before I realized my component had the `OnPush` configured.

Comment: why it's not working with onPush even I tried marking component as markForCheck or detectChanges?

Answer (score 0):

I am using `Angular 15` in one of my projects with the latest version `1.7` of `ng-circle-progress` and it's working fine for me. Here is my code.

`app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// Import ng-circle-progress
import { NgCircleProgressModule } from 'ng-circle-progress';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgCircleProgressModule.forRoot({
      radius: 100,
      outerStrokeWidth: 16,
      innerStrokeWidth: 8,
      outerStrokeColor: "#78C000",
      innerStrokeColor: "#C7E596",
      animationDuration: 300
    })

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Inside my `app-component.html` I have included it directly

```
<circle-progress
  [percent]="85"
  [radius]="100"
  [outerStrokeWidth]="16"
  [innerStrokeWidth]="8"
  [outerStrokeColor]="'#78C000'"
  [innerStrokeColor]="'#C7E596'"
  [animation]="true"
  [animationDuration]="300"
></circle-progress>
```

Can you please check your `CSS` code as well just to ensure that your circular progress is visible?

Hope that helps

Comment: I checked my css and it shows. I am getting this error though: **core.mjs:8506 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `EnvironmentInjector#runInContext`. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203
Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `EnvironmentInjector#runInContext`. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203**